# warning in Xcode 9.3

Tags: swift, swift4.1

I'm getting this warning in Xcode when I run my app in the simulator. What can I do to get rid of it?

```
objc[6529]: Class VCWeakObjectHolder is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/Frameworks/ViceroyTrace.framework/ViceroyTrace (0x13490b4d0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference (0x133a37e38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Can't find a single reference on Internet to 'Class VCWeakObjectHolder'. It is driving me nuts... although it is just a warning.

Update: Xcode 9.3.1 and Xcode 9.4 beta both give the same warning.

[image]

Comment: How many Xcode you have in Applications directory ?

Comment: Only Xcode 9.3 in the Applications directory. And Xcode 8 on an external volume. But even if that is not mounted I'm getting the same warning.

Comment: the warning was also in the betas... (and now in the release version).

Comment: I would try resetting the simulator content, Xcode 9.3 has a bunch of weird issues but maybe that would help solve your problem.

Comment: I tried resetting as you advised, Echizzle. But no luck... same warning.

Comment: What all frameworks are you importing? Can you post a screenshot of them(general tab screenshot). Also there are you using any framework called ViceroyTrace?

Comment: I did Harish. Guess I can remove one of them? Whey are some items in my Project Navigator red? And no I don't know what ViceroyTrace is or does. Probably came with one of the cocoapods? Thanks, Jan

Comment: removing one of the Pods_Macaws.framework with the 'minus sign' doesn't work... + is active, - not.

Answer (score 0):

I had this warning for more than a month. First I checked the both paths, to check if the frameworks were duplicated for some reason, but did not delete anything, then I finally tried this and it worked for me:

1. **Reset** the **simulator** (Menu: Hardware -> Erase all content and settings ... )
2. **Clean** the project (Command + Shift + K)
3. **Clean** the **build folder** (Command + Option + Shift + K)
4. **Run** the code on the simulator again